# use conditional logging via domino api

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-extlib

I want to implement the logging to openlog.nsf functionality from the domino api in an application.

However in the current setup of the application logging (to Domino console) only occurs when this is enabled for the whole application via a configuration property e.g.

```
public static void writeToConsole(String msg){
if (getDeugMode() ==true) {
System.out.println(msg);
}
}
```

usage:

```
writeToConsole("hello world");
```

I am wondering how I could rewrite the writeToConsole method to utilize the XspOpenLogLogUtil class?

Comment: You could create wrapper methods like *writeToConsoleWarning* and *writeToConsoleDebug*. In these methods you can check the current log level and call the *writeToConsole* method if the current log level is set.

Comment: I think I can live with that. Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

`XspOpenLogUtil.logErrorEx(Throwable, String, Level, Document)` will allow you to pass a custom message.

Also `XspOpenLogUtil.getOpenLogItem()` gets a handle on the `OpenLogItem` object. From there you can use any of the inner methods.

See this page https://wiki.openntf.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6586418 (all the method names are the same, the class in ODA is just `XspOpenLogUtil` instead of `OpenLogUtil`.

In my apps I usually have a wrapper method `handleException(Throwable t)` which calls XspOpenLogUtil.logError()` anyway and that's what I would recommend. It gives greater flexibility for handling e.g. different logging levels like this or changing the logging framework, should you so wish in the future.

Comment: you mean I can not create a xspopenlogutil object first and pass that in a function?

Comment: XspOpenLogUtil is just a static class, objects aren't intended to be created from it. `getXspOpenItem()` creates the item, if it doesn't already exist, and returns it. So you may be able to use that to create and set relevant properties, then pass to a function that just calls logError(). But XspOpenLogUtil just writes to OpenLog, not the console.